# How to list the containers attached to a given user-defined network?

Tags: docker

I'm reworking a bunch of scripts using the deprecated `docker run --link` option in favor of user-defined bridges.

By searching in the doc, I didn't find any command to list all containers attached to a given network. For now, I am parsing the JSON output of [`docker network inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_inspect/) through the `jq` tool; I've posted that as an answer below since it may help someone. But, do you know another option to achieve that? Maybe using a dedicated Docker command, option or a custom Go format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `docker network inspect` command produces a JSON output that can be parsed using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to extract the relevant piece of information:

```
sudo docker network inspect app-bridge | jq '.[].Containers[].Name'

"app2"
"app3"
"app1"
"laughing_easley"
"database"
"thirsty_wing"
```

If you are already familiar with JSON processing with `jq`, the advantage is you can reinvest your knowledge without having to bother with [Go templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/). On the other hand, it relies on an external tool which may or may be not available at your site.